# Faster method to modify (TextToDisplay) of hyperlinks on a big range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, hyperlink

I am using the below code to modify `TextToDisplay` of hyperlinks for a column of 10k cells.
It works, but the code takes about 10 seconds to finish (on high end PC). 
I am seeking for a faster method to fulfil this task. 
I tried to put all the hyperlinks on an array ,but I got the below error on code

```
 Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = ws.Range("N2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
       Dim arr
         arr = rng.Hyperlinks ‘Run-time error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

This the working code, but it is slow. 
I also tried turn off `screenupdating` , but it make no difference.
In advance, grateful for any helpful comments and answers. 
[image]

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub Replace_Hyperlinks_TextToDisplay_Q()
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
     Dim LastRow As Long
      LastRow = ws.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
    Const str1 As String = "http://xxxxx/"
    Const str2 As String = "\"
 
    Dim i As Long
     For i = 2 To LastRow
       If ws.Range("O" & i).Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
          ws.Range("O" & i).Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay = Replace(Range("O" & i), str1, "")
          ws.Range("O" & i).Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay = Replace(Range("O" & i), str2, " - " & vbLf)
          ws.Range("O" & i).Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay = UCase(Left(ws.Range("O" & i).Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay, 1)) _
                                                         + Mid(ws.Range("O" & i).Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay, 2, _
                                                           Len(ws.Range("O" & i).Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay))
        End If
      Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` may help a little. Don't forget to set them back to `True` at the end of the sub

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad ,I tried but the difference is a fraction of 1 second

Comment: That's why I said _may_ and as @BigBen said, this is likely as fast as you can get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can replace the `Range.TextToDisplay` value using an array just like any other value.  I haven't tested this on a large range but it should be significantly faster than iterating over the cells.

```
Sub Replace_Hyperlinks_TextToDisplay_Q2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Const str1 As String = "http://xxxxx/"
    Const str2 As String = "\"
    
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set Target = .Range("O1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Data = Target.Value
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
          Data(r, 1) = Replace(Data(r, 1), str1, "")
          Data(r, 1) = Replace(Data(r, 1), str2, " - " & vbLf)
          Data(r, 1) = UCase(Left(Data(r, 1), 1)) & Mid(Data(r, 1), 2, Len(Data(r, 1)))
    Next
    
    Target.Value = Data
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: It works like a speed of rocket, your code toke 0.4 seconds to finish 